Why can't I create the syntax highlight for .py for my color scheme
I'm trying to create my own color scheme for vim, I even managed to define some things like the background color, status bar color, Pmenu, Strings...
I tried creating a file called:
.vim/syntax/python3.vim

with the following code:
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo set filetype=foo
syn keyword pythonStatement     False None True
hi pythonStatement guifg=#D84256

I also tried using the preferred groups just to see if it would work, then I tried using highlight within the color scheme and it still didn't work. Syntax highlighting only worked if I typed the command in the command bar, but not in .vim...
I just wanted to create my own syntax highlighting for python and I intended to create it for other languages ​​as well, such as html, css, javascript, and a few others.

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set filetype=python

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


The first line in your ~/.vim/syntax/python3.vim file:
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo set filetype=foo

which should really be:
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set filetype=python3

handles filetype-detection. As such, it belongs to:
~/.vim/ftdetect/python3.vim


The second line:
syn keyword pythonStatement False None True

is fine as-is, and where it should be.

The third line:
hi pythonStatement guifg=#D84256

is doubly wrong.
The only hi commands that should be in a syntax script are of the form:
hi link myCustomGroup SomeDefaultGroup

where your custom highlight group is linked to a default one. In this case, it should look like:
hi link pythonStatement Statement

Then, in your colorscheme, you can do something like:
hi Statement guifg=#D84256



Now… the default python syntax script already supports Python 3 for *.py files so I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, here.

I want to set a custom python highlight for my color scheme, but I've tried one way and another without success. I tried creating my own and using existing python highlight groups, but it didn't work unless I put it inside vim temporarily :hi pythonStatement guifg=#D84256

Regarding the line (autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo set filetype=foo) I just wrote it wrong here.

What does "I want to set a custom python highlight for my color scheme" mean? Do you want your colorscheme to highlight existing language-specific highlight groups differently than the default groups they are linked to, in GVim? If yes, then all you have to do is add lines like hi pythonStatement guifg=#D84256 to your colorscheme.

Maybe a confusion between syntax files (what to highlight) and colorschemes (how to highlight)?

Yes, that would be my working hypothesis.

Eu queria mudar a syntax do python e de outras para se encaixarem melhor para o esquema de cores que estou fazendo, mas eu mudava um, dói, três e nada alterava aparentemente, por isso tentei criar minha própria syntax. Eu procurei um tema mais simples, e consegui definir a syntax com sucesso, a base do tema deserto que eu estava usando não tinha me ajudado muito, mas agora que eu usei uma base mais simples eu já resolvi o problema. Mas obrigado por vir me ajudar.

In english, please.
